# implementing redis script rollback on error

Tags: redis, lua

If a redis lua script fails halfway through, is there any way to rollback the changes?

I.e, calling this via EVAL, the current code will add one to the key then throw

```lua
local function inc2 (key)
  redis.call('INCRBY',key,1)
  error("FAIL")
  redis.call('INCRBY',key,1)
end

return inc2(KEYS[1])
```

I'd like to be able to have a way of rolling back the first `INCRBY` so that it does nothing on error.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: NO. There's no way to roll back.

Comment: @for_stack I'll be happy to accept your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your first attempt to increment in a `pcall()`

```
local function inc2( key )
    local success, msg = pcall( redis.call( 'INCR', key ) )

    if success then
        redis.call( 'INCR', key )
    else
        error( msg )
        redis.call( 'DECR', key )
    end
end

inc2( KEYS[1] )
```

---

Seems to me it would be more effective to check if the value is within bounds to begin with.

```
local function inc2( key, max )
    if redis.call( 'get', key ) < max then
        redis.call( 'INCRBY', key, 2 )
    end
end

inc2( KEYS[1], 20 )
```

Comment: Not entirely certain why it'd be used, as it shouldn't increment if it fails, right?  Maybe it fails for another reason, ex post facto, out of bounds or something...  Well, this's how to do it, anyway.

Comment: thanks! I was mainly asking because I've always read that redis eval operations were atomic and it seemed like when a script errors halfway through, the database can be left in a partial state. I was looking to figure out if there was a way around it but now it seems that the only way to not be in the partial state is to not error in the script itself.